# Host-Named Site Collections configuration

Tags: site-collection, web-application

I am configuring SharePoint Server 2013 for Host-Named Site Collections & creating Initial Site Collections.

Created a new Web Application to handle Host-Named Site Collections (HNSC):

i)Created a new IIS web site:
(1) Name: SharePoint HNSC Host – 80
(2) Port: 80

ii) Application Pool:
(1) Created a new application pool:
(2) Application Pool Name: SharePoint Default HNSC AppPool

Created a default, not template site collection at the root of the web application:
a) Opened SharePoint 2013 Management Shell:

$hnscWebApp = Get-SPWebApplication | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -eq "SharePoint HNSC Host - 80"}

New-SPSite -Name "Root HNSC Site Collection" -Url "http://????" -HostHeaderWebApplication
$hnscWebApp -OwnerAlias "????\Administrator"

New-SPSite -Name "????" -Url "http://????" –HostHeaderWebApplication $hnscWebApp -Template "STS#0" -OwnerAlias "????\Administrator"

New-SPSite -Name "????" -Url "http://????" –HostHeaderWebApplication $hnscWebApp -Template "DEV#0" -OwnerAlias "????\Administrator"

But I am getting an error message "" New-SPSite: cannot find an SPWebApplication object that contains the following name""

Can someone help me to replace ???? with correct values please?

Comment: I see you make the IIS web site and app pool, was this done in IIS manually or via the add web application in Central Admin?

Comment: I am trying to add a site collection by the SharePoint 2013 management shell.

Comment: when you get the $hnscWebApp object, explore it, try just typing in the object name by itself. it should return the display name and the URL.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to point you to the corresponding technet page:

[Deployment and configuration for host-named site collections](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc424952.aspx#section2)

Lets do this from the beginning

```
#get the one web app that will hold all host named site collections
$hnscWebApp = Get-SPWebApplication | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -eq "SharePoint HNSC Host - 80"}

#get the url of the web app
$hnscWebAppUrl = $hnscWebApp.Url
#the variable will hold for example: http://hnsc-hostwebapp.company.local

#the hnsc web app hosting all hnsc should have a root site collection
New-SPSite -Name "Root HNSC Site Collection" -Url "$hnscWebAppUrl" -OwnerAlias "YOURDOMAIN\Administrator"

#create a new hnsc with a dedicated url
New-SPSite -Name "Teamsite" -Url "http://teamsite.company.local" –HostHeaderWebApplication $hnscWebApp -Template "STS#0" -OwnerAlias "YOURDOMAIN\Administrator"

#create a dedicated dev site on a dedicated url
New-SPSite -Name "SPDev site" -Url "http://spdev.company.local" –HostHeaderWebApplication $hnscWebApp -Template "DEV#0" -OwnerAlias "YOURDOMAIN\Administrator"

#create a managed managed path for hnsc
New-SPManagedPath "sites" -HostHeader

#create a path based site on a hnsc team url
New-SPSite -Name "Teamsite for Marketing" -Url "http://teamsite.company.local/sites/marketing" –HostHeaderWebApplication $hnscWebApp -Template "STS#0" -OwnerAlias "YOURDOMAIN\Administrator"
```